# async appears to not use multiple threads C++

Tags: c++, c++11, async-await

my async calls appear to run in serial execution .. leaving me to believe Im not doing something correctly in the code or.. perhaps not understanding something

At a high level I take in 100,000 or so strings, use them to perform a query rate limited to 1 per second per connection.. I am starting with 4 connections to the service and want to use all 4 concurrently .. wait for all their answers to come back and then combine the results

Main.cpp

```
  
  struct DataFetcher {
    DataFetcher(cpool::ConnectionPool& tws_conn_pool): conn_pool(&conn_pool){
      std::cout << "DataFetcher() this->conn_pool == "<< this->conn_pool << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> process_data(std::vector<std::string> sub_batch_vector){

      std::for_each(sub_batch_vector.begin(), sub_batch_vector.end(),[](std::string query_str){
        std::cout << query_str << ";";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
      });

      cpool::ConnectionPool::ConnectionProxy proxy_conn = this->my_conn_pool->get_connection();

      proxy_conn->is_healthy();

      // will do more stuff later here

      return sub_batch_vector;
    }

    cpool::ConnectionPool * const tws_conn_pool;
  };
```

What is the proper way to use this async call within a loop.. there will be a variable number of ServiceConnections available so I'd like to do something like this

```
std::vector<std::future<std::vector<std::string>>> results_vector;

for (int i=0 ; i < this->tws_conn_pool->size()-1; i++) {
      
  std::vector<std::string> subvector = {queries_list.begin() + (batch_size*i), queries_list.begin() + (batch_size*(i+1))};

  DataFetcher fetcher = DataFetcher(*this->conn_pool);

  auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, &DataFetcher::process_data, &fetcher, subvector);
      
  results_vector.push_back(fut);
}
```

but this seems very obtuse and doesn't actually compile..

```
 from /Server/cpp_server/src/_server.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::future<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; _Args = {const std::future<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&}; _Tp = std::future<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:482:2:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::future<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; _Args = {const std::future<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&}; _Tp = std::future<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::future<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1189:30:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::future<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::future<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::future<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/Server/cpp_server/src/_server.cpp:175:35:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:145:20: error: use of deleted function ‘std::future<_Res>::future(const std::future<_Res>&) [with _Res = std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’
  145 |  noexcept(noexcept(::new((void *)__p)
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  146 |        _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)))
      |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Server/cpp_server/src/_server.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/9/future:782:7: note: declared here
  782 |       future(const future&) = delete;
      |       ^~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_server.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/_server.dir/src/_server.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/_server.dir/all] Error 2
```

Comment: It seems to me that any benefits here that might be gained from using multiple execution threads will be likely lost due to all the massive copying and duplication of all the vectors.

Comment: Undefined behaviour on passing local variable `&fetcher` to `std::async`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I guess I can attempt to pass the vector by reference.. along with a calculated range with which to perform the calculation ?

Comment: Your title says that `std::async` appears to not use multiple threads, but the question body says that the `std::async` version doesn't even compile. Which one is it?

Comment: And that, too -- `fetcher` will immediately go out of scope and get destroyed, leaving each execution thread holding a bag containing a pointer to a destroyed object, resulting in a spectacular crash. Multithreading is complicated, and difficult. This entire approach will not work.

Comment: @user17732522 , I made a switch in `results_vector` to array since the number of connections is predetermined.. and it compiles... works but.. I think based on all this feedback I need to get something that works.. but then backtrack to make it more efficient in terms of using vectors-subvectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have data fetcher take its pool by pointer.  Taking a refernece and immeditatel taking its address is silly.

Move the `fut` into the vector.  Futures cannot be copied, only moved.

Pass `fetcher` to async by value.  Pointers/references to local variables should not be passed to async.

Move the `subvector` into `async`.  Efficiency.

The future (or moved to destinations) produced by async blocks on the async task on destruction.

Comment: thanks Yakk - Adam , I will try to move the subvector.. but one thing I thought was off was you say by reference is bad idea to async.. isn't it bad to send things by value if those values are very very large vectors?

Comment: @Erik Nothing I told you to do involved copying a large object.  Moving is O(1) on the size of the vector.

Comment: and just to clarify by move you mean https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

Comment: @Erik No, I mean using the move constructor.  `std::move` is a common/easy way to trigger using the move constructor, so calling it often is involved (not always).  (`std::move` does not move; it casts to an rvalue reference, which (when you construct another object from that) can do the move).  Of course, this is sort of like "guns don't kill people, bullets do" insofar as `std::move` is the mechanism you often deliver a move construction by.  An example of moving without `std::move` is `vec.push_back( std::async( []{ std::cout << "hello world\n"; } ) );`.

Comment: @Erik To someone used to JS, an important thing about C++ is that it has values of object type that follow value semantics, not reference/pointer semantics.  In JS and other RC languages, object variables are almost always smart references to objects, not the objects themselves.  With C++, because they are the objects themselves, copying a variable makes a copy of the object; meanwhile, moving a variable moves its identity around if that makes sense.  This places a new demand on the programmer to pay attention to object lifetime.